# How can I generate the confidence value for each prediction of the target when using cost matrix on C5?

Tags: r, unbalanced-classes

I am using cost matrix for an unbalanced set `-70% (not enrolled: 0)-30% (enrolled:1) : error_cost <- matrix(c(0, 1.5, 1, 0), nrow = 2)`
I have not being able to run`prROCR = predict(SfEnrollModel12,Samford1316_test,type="prob")[,2]`, which I think would give me the probability for each prediction; is that right?

The only way now I know to plot ROC curve or calculate the AUC is using the type `prob` and I am getting error messages of invalid type:

> Error in predict.C5.0(SfEnrollModel12, Samford1316_test, type = "prob") : 
>     confidence values (i.e. class probabilities) should not be used with costs.

I also need to use the confidence level/value for each prediction as part of the decision process to accept the prediction on an individual level.

Is there any other way to get that for this kind of modeling?

Comment: It would be helpful if you added a tag to specify the software you are using.  This looks like [tag:r], but I'm not certain.

Comment: Yes, it is R; I still dont have figured this out. Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks